# node.js http GET - why isn't it returning to the calling function when an error is encountered?

Tags: node.js, promise

Can someone please tell me why, when "reject on request error" is encountered, this function doesn't return anything to the function that I'm calling it from?

I want an error message returned to the function that calls this, but it appears the the code just stops executing when the indicated error is encountered.

```
function httpRequest(options, postData) {
console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - begin');
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - a');
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - b');
        // reject on bad status
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
            console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - error: bad status ' + res.statusCode);
            return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
        }
        // cumulate data
        var body = [];
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body.push(chunk);
        });
        // resolve on end
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - res.on end');
            try {
                console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - body = ' + body);
                body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest -  reject(e)');
                reject(e);
            }
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
    // reject on request error
    req.on('error', function(err) {
        // This is not a "Second reject", just a different sort of failure
        console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - req.on error (second) err = ' + err.response);
        reject(err); // *** <--- Why doesn't the error message here get returned to the calling function?
    });
    if (postData) {
        req.write(postData);
    } 
    req.end();
    console.log('DEBUG - httpRequest - req.end');
});
```

}

Comment: Are you handling the returned promise properly?

Comment: I'm calling it like this: httpRequest(options, function (error, curConditions){ 
     console.log('DEBUG - 164 - error = ' + error.response);
});

Based on my console.log statements, it appears that it's not returning error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `httpRequest` function takes two arguments, `options` and `postData`, and it returns a promise.

In [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973993/node-js-http-get-why-isnt-it-returning-to-the-calling-function-when-an-error#comment74978483_43973993), you're stating that you call it like this:

```
 httpRequest(options, function (error, curConditions) { ... });
```

That's incorrect for two reasons:

- the second argument you are passing isn't POST data, but a (callback) function;
- you're not handling the returned promise correctly;

The correct way of calling it:

```
httpRequest(options).then(function(curConditions) {
  ... // handle the result
}).catch(function(err) {
  ... // handle the error
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! That fixed it. I've been coding for many years, but I'm currently a n00b in regards to the asynchronous nature of node.js and working with promises.

Comment: I'll upvote you're answer once I'm able to do so (my account here is too new).